# How to display the images horizontally

Tags: css, html, image, figure

I am using figure tag to display the images. The images are added vertically. I tried using a div with style as display inline block. But it does not seem to work. I am clueless what is missing. Any idea on how to make it display horizontally.

```
<style>
figure {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
</style>


<figure>
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
</figure>
```

Comment: i think inline-block will work, but take note that if you're screen or window is smaller which the elements can't fit horizontally, it will go vertical.

Comment: You can easily find some answers by simply google it and there are so many ways to do it.

Comment: Yes I did google and found inline-block may work but it doesnot seem to work. Then later i understood there are other styles in my page that overrides.

Answer (score 2):

Apply this css,

```
figure {
    display : inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have done is you have specified images to be displayed as **block** in your CSS -
  `display: block;`

What you need is them to be displayed as **inline**,

Try this edited code of yours -

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        figure {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 1em;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            margin-left: 40px;
            margin-right: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <figure>
      <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
    </figure>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

here

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://www.jonathanjeter.com/images/Square_200x200.png" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://www.jonathanjeter.com/images/Square_200x200.png" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://www.jonathanjeter.com/images/Square_200x200.png" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://www.jonathanjeter.com/images/Square_200x200.png" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://www.jonathanjeter.com/images/Square_200x200.png" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

Responsive web design:

```
<style>
.grid_1 { width: 15.625%; } /* 125px/800px = 15.625% */
.grid_2 { width: 32.5%; } /* 260px/800px = 32.5% */
.grid_3 { width: 49.375%; } /* 395px/800px = 49.375% */
.grid_4 { width: 65.625%; } /* 525px/800px = 65.625% */
.grid_5 { width: 83.125%; } /* 665px/800px = 83.125% */
.grid_6 { width: 100%; } /* 800px/800px = 100% */

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6 {
  margin-right: 0;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
</style>

<figure class="grid_1">
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
</figure>
<figure class="grid_1">
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
</figure>
<figure class="grid_1">
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
</figure>
<figure class="grid_1">
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
</figure>
```